# Regex: match at least 3 characters in a string in specific order

Tags: php, regex, string

How to search within a given string so that every 3 (or more) character **ordered** coincidence is captured? I am using it for applying some conditional restrictions in an HTML search input...
My best try so far:

```
/[deleted]{3,}/g
```

I need "**del**", "**ele**", "**let**", "**ete**" or "**ted**" to be captured... But also "**dele**", "**eted**" or even the full "**deleted**". The preceding regex does the trick, but the problem now is the order of the characters, because it also captures strings like "**ltd**" or "**eded**", which are not in order with the word and should not.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why regex. Check for substring. In JS `'deleted'.includes(inputString)`. In PHP `strpos('deleted', $inputString) !== false`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Prevent the user from searching for 'deleted'?

Comment: @Tushar, the strpos solution would not let me do the 'at least 3 characters' restriction...

Comment: To add restriction you can check the `length`.

Comment: @user2182349 No, the full 'deleted' string should also be captured. So if I do it with a regex, I will be able to easily maintain the conditions in a near future, which is what I want. And that is another reason to choose regex...

Comment: @Tushar, but in the future it will also be possible to search for 'deleted', 'added', 'edited', and so on... And with strpos + length, there will be too many conditions...

Comment: Perhaps PHP's similar_text function would help

Comment: @user2182349 Need to be exact coincidences.

Comment: Then use @Tushar's approach with an array

Comment: @andcl you need regx like [https://regex101.com/r/KkJeho/8](https://regex101.com/r/KkJeho/8)

Comment: @andcl  check once my answer and let me know.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally have found a solution that takes into account all of the restrictions. **It was a matter of misunderstanding on my part**. Sorry. 
But thanks for all the replies and comments anyway:

Before posting the question, I started with the PHP solution as (I thought) @Tushar suggested in his first comment:

```
strpos('deleted', $inputString) !== false
```

But as it did not work as expected, I went for regex. The problem is what I really tested before the question was:

```
strpos($inputString, 'deleted') !== false
```

I exchanged the '*haystack*' and the '*needle*', resulting in unwanted results, so I ended up asking here in stackoverflow...
Summing up, the solution from @Tushar is absolutely correct. Credits to him.
Thanks mate.